# Selenium Get all child element text but skip some child element text under certain condition

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get all child element text but skip some child element text under certain condition which is the  and  part in Selenium using Python language

Source Code

```
<div class="example-info">
    <div class="line1">
        ゆえありげな 
        <ruby>
            <rb>品</rb>
            <rp>(</rp>
            <rt roma="sina" hiragana="しな">しな</rt>
            <rp>)</rp>
        </ruby>
        "。"
    </div>
    <div class="line2">似有来历的物品。</div>
</div>
```

Expected Result

```
ゆえありげな品。
似有来历的物品。
```

Here is the website example:
https://www.mojidict.com/details/198951091?notationMode=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.mojidict.com/details/198951091?notationMode=1")

time.sleep(5)

total_text_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='example-info'])[8]")
total_text = total_text_element.text

undesired_text_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='example-info'])[8]/div/ruby/rt")
undesired_text = undesired_text_element.text

desired_text = total_text.replace(undesired_text, "")
desired_text = desired_text.replace("\n\n", "")
print(desired_text)
```

Please note that I have done this for a specific element and not all the elements. If you want to apply it to all the matching cases of the given `x-path`, then you have to incorporate some additional changes. First change will be using `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`.